# Store the google loggedin userdata into session using googleapi with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, google-api

I am trying to implement login with googleapi using  codeigniter.It is logged in fine.After login it is redirecting to another page.But what i want is after login store the data into session and use another view.then redirect to redirect redirect url.But it is once it is login redirect to redirect url. when i try to store the data into session it is not going there.I am new to this.Please somebody help me thanks in Advance.

```
<?php

    class HomeController extends CI_controller{

      public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Login_Model');
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/src/Google_Client.php';
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
      }

    public function glogin(){
      $clientId = '390448461087-ivmu5fq7nl67gt8qd09vu6ljh27eh6fg.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //Google client ID
      $clientSecret = '1qaO8Sa98zqSJU2J2xRFvsW9'; //Google client secret
      $redirectURL = base_url() .'Vendorcontroller/index/';

      //Call Google API
      $gClient = new Google_Client();
      $gClient->setApplicationName('Login with google');
      $gClient->setClientId($clientId);
      $gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
      $gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectURL);
      $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);


      if(isset($_GET['code']))
      {
        $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
      }

      if (isset($_SESSION['token']))
      {
        $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
      }

      if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
              $userData=$google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
        //when i try to save session data like below it is not coming here 
              $_SESSION['id']=$userData['id'];
              $_SESSION['email']=$userData['email'];
              $_SESSION['familyName']=$userData['familyName'];
              $_SESSION['gender']=$userData['gender'];
              $_SESSION['age']=$userData['age'];
              $_SESSION['picture']=$userData['picture'];
              $_SESSION['givenName']=$userData['givenName'];
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($userData);
         die;
          }
      else
      {
          $url = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
          header("Location: $url");
              exit;
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have change the redirecturl it is worked for me

```
<?php

    class HomeController extends CI_controller{

      public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Login_Model');
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/src/Google_Client.php';
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
      }

    public function glogin(){
      $clientId = '390448461087-ivmu5fq7nl67gt8qd09vu6ljh27eh6fg.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //Google client ID
      $clientSecret = '1qaO8Sa98zqSJU2J2xRFvsW9'; //Google client secret
      $redirectURL = base_url() .'HomeController/glogin/';

      //Call Google API
      $gClient = new Google_Client();
      $gClient->setApplicationName('Login with google');
      $gClient->setClientId($clientId);
      $gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
      $gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectURL);
      $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);


      if(isset($_GET['code']))
      {
        $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
      }

      if (isset($_SESSION['token']))
      {
        $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
      }

      if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
              $userData=$google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
        //when i try to save session data like below it is not coming here 
              $_SESSION['id']=$userData['id'];
              $_SESSION['email']=$userData['email'];
              $_SESSION['familyName']=$userData['familyName'];
              $_SESSION['gender']=$userData['gender'];
              $_SESSION['age']=$userData['age'];
              $_SESSION['picture']=$userData['picture'];
              $_SESSION['givenName']=$userData['givenName'];
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($userData);
         die;
          }
      else
      {
          $url = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
          header("Location: $url");
              exit;
          }
    }
}
```